# How to set Viewport camera (NOT 3D scene camera) default settings?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

How do you set the default settings of the Viewport camera (the 'camera' that allows you to see into a viewport as you open blender.)(NOT 3D scene camera)? Because of our workflow in the office I have to change the default units and that result in the scene camera zoomed way in and when I dolly out the whole scene disappears because the clip limits are now super small! I know to change the properties of this camera in the'View' dropdown on the RHS of the 3D window but that is not a setting that 'sticks'? Where can i set those default values? Is it in preferences somewhere? Thanks

EDIT: Attached test .blend file

[image]

So the 'Save as Startup' cameras are fine (see below):

[image]

But when I change any other window to a 3D viewport (ie: the Shader Editor, below) the camera in that view reverts to the not very useful 'default' 50mm. It's that 'default' I want to change.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: After making those changes to the viewport camera, go to *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*

Comment: One would think so, but with every new 3D Viewport you create / drag out (as we need to do in our workflow) it defaults back to the stock factory setting camera. So, no, unfortunately that is not a solution to this issue.

Comment: Hello :). I cannot seem to reproduce your issue in Blender 2.81. When i change the viewport camera to 85mm, all newly created viewports use 85mm. Would you mind [sharing your empty .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ I think he means when they create new Workspaces or are splitting areas rather than just starting a new file

Comment: @stphnl329 Well, in both of these cases it works just fine. Just tested it. Newly created workspace gets settings from the startup file, so your solution still applies :).

Comment: Sorry, how do you add a blend file?

Comment: Save the defualt file, upload it to that link and paste the given code into your question